# vertical align multicolumn heading

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicol

I created a table using this code:

```
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering\ra{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rcccccc@{}}
\toprule &  \textit{Accuracy} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Time}} \\
\cmidrule{4-6} &&& $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ 
\\ \midrule
$c$ & 9 && 1 & 1 & 3\\
$c$ & 9 && 1 & 1 & 3\\
$c$ & 9 && 1 & 1 & 3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
```

How can I align the heading "Accuracy" to middle of the row (the red text in the picture)?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to modify the code, here is the \ra code: \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `multirow` package and replace `\textit{Accuracy}` by `\multirow{2}{*}[-3pt]{Accuracy}` (args are: number of rows, width (* for natural width), fine tuning vertical position (optional), text).